# How can JavaDocs be configured to be generated in a specified project root directory?

Tags: java, gradle, github-pages, publish, javadoc

I want to generate my JavaDocs into a given directory in my project root, I know that the `destinationDir` property exists, but how do I use it also given that my `build.gradle` exists within a directory inside of my project root. I provided a small diagram below:

```
/projectRoot
  /lib
    /build/docs/javaDocs <--- JavaDocs here by default
    build.gradle
  /docs <---- Need JavaDocs here
```

Taking a look at the documentation for JavaDocs in gradle, [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html). I knew that the destinationDir property existed so I attempted to set it like the provided example. This didn't have the intended affect and instead generated nothing, or is it going something outside of my project directory?

```
tasks.withType(Javadoc).configureEach {
    exclude ('com/nest/egg/**')
    options.addStringOption("charset", "utf-8")
    options.addStringOption("docencoding", "utf-8")
    options.addStringOption("encoding", "utf-8")
    destinationDir = reporting.file("docs") // Also tried "/docs", "docs/"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a Java `File` object to `destinationDir` specifying your desired location<sup>1</sup>. So you can write:

```
destinationDir = layout.projectDirectory.dir("..").dir("docs").asFile
```

Here you are using Gradle's [`ProjectLayout`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/ProjectLayout.html) object. Each `dir()` call gives you a Gradle [`Directory`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/Directory.html) so you must finally call `asFile` to finally get the Java `File` object that you need.

---

<sup>1</sup>I am not sure what object you are using when you call `reporting.file("docs")` but the `ProjectLayout` object gives you all you need.